# Degrading streaming video performance (Google Chrome and 15.10)

Tags: video, google-chrome, performance

I'm currently running Ubuntu 15.10 and the latest beta of Google Chrome 48.0.2564.48, and whenever I try and stream video through Chrome, performance drops off rapidly. I can start a video, but after a couple of minutes it stutters, and eventually stops.

Looking at "top" in another window shows a rising load average (increasing through 4-5 when performance begins to drop) and when this reaches c. 10, the computer stops responding altogether. This seems to show a lot of chrome processes, even when running in incognito mode with no extensions active.

I thought this might be an Adobe Flash issue, so I uninstalled that and am now running an opensource Flash player, but performance is still choppy (and even for Html5 video).

What could be causing this? Is this a Ubuntu issue or a Chrome issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears (after much fiddling about) that it was a unity/compiz issue. I have sorted it by switching to GNOME and using a different desktop manager which doesn't appear to take up that much CPU.